# How to change Machine Key generated by Visual Studio ASP.NET MVC Project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, encryption, cryptography, key

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC Web App with Office 365 authentication. The web app runs perfectly on my computer, but when I transfer and run the project on other computers and on Azure, it gave me a Cryptographic Operation Error. After some research, I concluded that the Machine Keys are the ones causing the problem.

I have found the MachineKey for the Azure Web App Service, but when I put it in my local Web.Config, it still looks for my computer's original Machine Key. The same happens when I set it to auto-generate, both my computer and Azure throw the same error.

I need a way to reset the Machine Key my application is looking for. For example, if I set the Machine Key in Web.config to "KEY_EXAMPLE_HERE", my application will start to use that key. That way, I can set up the same Machine Key in all servers I need to run my application.

I don't know if the application looks for the key it generated when I created the Visual Studio project, but I need a way to change it.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!